# Looking for list of binary file extensions

Tags: go, binary, file-extension

I need a quick estimate if file is binary/text looking just at its extension, errors are acceptable.

Example: all images, audio, video are considered binary (i.e. `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.mp4`, etc.).

Are there any more or less complete lists I could use for this purpose? I also checked https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#TypeByExtension but it does not seem to be a good fit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are looking for a MIME type list. There is this great resource [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) that gives a large list of each type and their content.

It looks like the [mime package](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/) is a perfect fit for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with http://www.file-extensions.org/filetype/extension/name/bitmap-image-files scrapping...

Just inject jQuery and execute something like:

```
var rAN = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"); 
var extList = $('.color3').map(function(){
    return $(this).html();
}).get().filter(function(e){
    return rAN.test(e);
})
JSON.stringify(extList);
```

which should give a JSON representation of currently listed extensions =)

Answer (score 0):

That package seems exactly what you want. How is it not a good fit?

Basically, if the MIME type does not include "text" then it's binary.